# make the 'this' keyword refer to the calling object (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, this

I have read a couple of topics about this , however , I still can't figure it out .
simply what i need is letting the 'this' statement refer to the object that is calling the function , while it appears to be referring to the window ..

my function looks like this:

```
function  bckClr(clr){
var elmnt=this;
elmnt.style.background-color=clr;
}
```

and i call it like this:

```
< div > onmouseover="bckClr(#ff0000)">Lorim ipsum dolor sit amet.. < /div >
```

Comment: `onmouseover="bckClr.call(this, '#ff0000')"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
<div onmouseover="bckClr(this, '#ff0000')">Lorim ipsum dolor sit amet.. </div>
```

and then:

```
function  bckClr(elmnt, clr){
   elmnt.style.backgroundColor=clr;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Updated using CamelCase for the sytle property, noted by Pranav Kapoor.

Comment: Does `elmnt.style.background-color=clr;` work?
I've always used `elem.style.backgroundColor = clr`

Comment: You are right, the correct syntax is that, also noted in jbabey answer, mine is a copy from OP's code, will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: agreed, it was pseudo code , i'm not even using that background-color property , I just needed the 'this' thing.

Answer (score 2):

Separate your javascript from your markup:

```
<div id="thediv">Lorim ipsum dolor sit amet.. </div>
```

and:

```
var bckClr = function (element, color) {
    // notice the property is camel cased, not hyphenated
    element.style.backgroundColor = color;
};

document.getElementById('thediv').onmouseover = function () {
    bckClr(this, '#ff0000');
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L9DRF/3/

Answer (score 1):

Use an event listener instead of an inline handler.

HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv">Lorim ipsum dolor sit amet.. </div>
```

JS:

```
function  bckClr(elmnt, clr){
   elmnt.style.backgroundColor=clr;
}
document.getElementById("mydiv").addEventListener("mouseover",function(){bckClr(this, '#ff0000');})
```